# SERIAL datatype in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

The use of `SERIAL` datatype is to auto increment the value, so there is no need to specify the value during insertion of values. If we create a
table and insert value to that table, by default values starts from 1 for `SERIAL` column datatype. But Instead of 1 is there any way to start the value from 100 and increment by 10 as default value?

Answer (score 4):

`Serial` is just syntactic sugaring on top of an `int` column that takes its value from a sequence. While you can't control a `serial` column's definitions directly, you could use an explicit sequence definition instead:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq INCREMENT BY 10 START WITH 100; -- Here!
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`alter`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altersequence.html) your existing sequence(*not matter whether its serial or what*) like below

```
ALTER SEQUENCE mytbl_id_seq INCREMENT 10 RESTART with 100
```

---

When creating a table

```
create table mytbl (id serial,val int)
```

a sequence will automatically creates i.e

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE mytbl_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  START 1
```

so you can alter this with your desired values i.e

```
  ALTER SEQUENCE mytbl_id_seq 
    INCREMENT 10 
    RESTART with 100
```

---

[`sqlfiddle-demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab268/4)